# MySite Quota - based on Version History?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, my-site, mysite, quota, storage-quota

We use SharePoint 2016 on-prem and the User's MySite quota is set to 5GB but apparently it's nearly full. However, when the user checks the actual size of the file stored locally on his device, it is less than what's stated in SP.

Why is that, I wondered!? Then I checked the Version History of the file, and indeed when you summarise (add up) all the version history and its relevant size then it comes up to the size indicated.

This cannot be an accurate presentation of the data file size though.
How would you approach this problem?

Clearly, the file size is way too small for the SP to say "running out of space".
 Do I simply delete the version history and if so; does it imply any issues?

Here is a picture for demo:

[image]

Comment: Update: after deleting so many Version History (manually) I got the total used space to 3.2GB and technically I have almost 2GB free of space! However, the quoata warning is still present and it still states 0.0GB free out of 5GB. How do I reset this to calculate the actual values?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Looks like that the MySite templates has been set by default so it has unlimited versioning of updated files. This also leads for the MySite Quote to build up and warn the user when is due to get full.

What is the solution:

Either to increase the MySite Quote or manually delete the Version History of each big file then to limit the Versioning of the document to 5 major changes for example and lastly to empty the RecycleBin.

All this solves the problem :) 
Howerver, doing this for every user can be tiring and maybe PowerShell would be an option.